# Prevent Angular from changing select box on initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my form, Angular is watching select boxes for changes, and then using the selected data to load in the data for later select boxes. This works fine, except on initialization of the watchers Angular will not keep the existing data with a selected option (as provided by the server) and instantly load in new data.

```
<form action="join" method="post" ng-controller="JoinController">
...

<select name="state" ng-model="state">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    ...data provided on initial load...
</select>

<select name="institution_id" ng-model="institutionId" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in institutionOptions">
    <option value="">{{ defaultInstitutionOption }}</option>
    ...data provided on initial load...
</select>

...
</form>
```

And the Angular controller...

```
app.controller('JoinController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.defaultInstitutionOption = "Select state...";

    $scope.$watch('state', function() {
        $scope.defaultInstitutionOption = "Loading institutions...";

        $http.get('institutions?state=' + encodeURIComponent($scope.state)).success(function(institutions) {
            $scope.institutionOptions = institutions;
            $scope.defaultInstitutionOption = "Select...";
        });
    }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$watch` takes 2 arguments `newValue` and `oldValue`. For the first request `oldValue` would be null or undefined.
Check something like

```
$scope.$watch('state', function(newValue,oldValue) {
//Check logic based on newValue and oldValue
}
```